# How to get access single value in associative array of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller and model.

Please help me in view pages `abc` to display a specific column in the table field.

```php
public function abc()
{
    $n=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $svc['id'] =$this->Admin_model->getallserv($n);
    $this->load->view('abc',$svc);
}

public function getallserv($n)
{
    $sql = "select * from services where id=$n";     
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);   
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: use `row_array()`  instead of `result()` with `limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

- Update `$query->result()` to `$query->row_array()`
- Then result    will be like `array('column_name' => 'value','column_name' =>    'value'.........)`
- assign to  `$svc` and in view you can access values like $svc->column_name

Code:

```
public function abc()
{
    $n=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $svc =$this->Admin_model->getallserv($n);
    $this->load->view('abc',$svc);
}
    
public function getallserv($n)
{
  $sql = "select * from services where id=$n";     
  $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
  return  $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: We should see `get_where()` or similar used in the model.  We should not see variables directly written into the sql string.  I do not endorse this answer.